# Convert Time to Minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the time in minutes . My time format is like this

```
21:30
```

I need to convert this time in minutes.

I tried with the following code:

```
 function TimetoMintues(hour,mint){
        var time = parseInt( hour * 60 );
        time = mint + time;
        return time;
    }
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: That's not a very complicated challenge. What have you tried to solve it? What part of the problem are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Please show your effort. SO isn't a free coding service

Comment: @CodeDifferent i used following code on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your time is in 24 hour format, try this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7vc45s6m/)

```
var time = "1:30";
timeArr = time.split( ":" );
var minutes = timeArr[ 0 ] * 60 + timeArr[ 1 ] * 1;
console.log( minutes );
```

Comment: Arg, I was stuck in Python mode for some reason. All right, have at it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer :-)